# TypeError: Cannot read property 'contacts' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reduce

it only displays contacts undefined.
i have index.s which is the main reducer which points to contact Reducer.js and i connect the provider with my component Contact.js

**Contacts.js**
[image]
**index.js the maine reducer**
[image]
**contactReducer.js reducer of contacts**

[image]

Comment: Please post actual code instead of pictures of code.

Comment: could you post your code in codesandbox or smth similar?

Comment: can you post the store.js file too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is that `state.myContact` in `mapStateToProps` is undefined. Make sure you are creating your store and passing it to your Provider.

Something like this from the docs: https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store/#configuring-your-store

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers' <-- this is your main reducer index.js, where you export the combineReducers
import App from './components/App'

const store = createStore(rootReducer) <--- make sure you have this line

render(
  <Provider store={store}>             <-- and this line
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

---

The second place where you try and use contacts is in the line

`const { contacts } = this.props`

If `this.props` is undefined, you cant grab `contacts` out of it.

In Contacts.js you need a constructor to make sure props is defined. Add a constructor that calls `super(props)`.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}
```

I found the info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted. When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise, this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to bugs.

This might only apply if you are trying to use props in the constructor though, so it might not be the issue but worth a shot.